# Using Handlebars in Jade

Tags: html, handlebars.js, pug

I have a html file I would like to convert it into a Jade file.
The only problem I don't know how or if it's possible to use handlebars in Jade.

Example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>{{title}}<small> <br /> {{description}}</small></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried something like this

```
.container<div class="row"><h1>{{title}}<small> <br /> {{description}}</small></h1></div>
```

Doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You're still using regular HTML tags in your template - that's not allowed. Writing this in jade, it should look like:

```
.container
  .row
    h1 {{title}}
      small
        br
        {{description}}
```

Though, I don't get the `h1 > small > br` part, I'd do it that way:

```
.container
  .row
    h1 {{title}}
    small {{description}}
```

Comment: oh the <br /> shouldn't be there I'm sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help!